# XCode : reasons for not using Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, libraries

I'm a new iPhone dev and I integrated a team of iOS developper, in the domain of education. First, I thank you for your help.

Here is my question : The lead developper told that for the project (iOS 5), they will not use Core Data to deal with the database of the app, but they will use their own SQLite libraries.
I have been told by the lead dev that Core Data will not fit in that project, because of the data they are dealing with... No more details

Since Core Data uses SQLite, (and so will the library they created), do you have any ideas why Core Data could be a problem (in general)

I really thank you if you have any clue.

**EDIT :**

I've just learnt that the lead is creating an sqlite database and we are going to use it in the app. And the fields contains a lot of html (a lot of special characters like \ or & or <), and we are going to display it in some UIWebViews. Is he right when he says that those special characters can turn wrong with core data ?

Comment: As far as I worked on core data, I can tell that there should not be a problem. Core data is little difficult to use syntactically so its usage is avoided. This may be one of the reason to avoid using it. Otherwise its really rich framework

Comment: I am with @hpiOSCoder on this, your lead developer or other team members are probably relying on their own libraries because they know them well, and not Core Data. This is by the way a good reason to stick with those libraries, but as Core Data can do a lot of heavy lifting for your team maybe during the development you can point them to how Core Data could have helped them (assuming you will continue to read about it to learn all about it).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. I'm going to speak to the lead to have his reasons. I don't think it is because it's difficult to learn, because he told me he liked core data.
Is the fact that there already is a preexisting sqlite database they are going to manually import to the app a reason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is cross-platform portability.  If you use a manually-generated schema, and perhaps even provide common library code, then that database schema/library can be used on non-Apple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess at other people's reasons but....  The purpose of Core Data is object persistence.  The fact that it **can** use a database as a storage mechanism is an implementation detail.  For problems that are specifically object-oriented in nature, it works very well.

If you are dealing with a problem that is more suited to solutions that are about rows, columns, and tables, it isn't necessarily a good fit.

I like using objects and have a lot of experience with Object/Relational mapping in other systems, so I tend to be pro-Core Data.  People with a database-only background probably have a different view.

Comment: I really like the way you narrated the programmer's perspective!